# when will the surfficient large power of a rational matrix be a integer matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, soft-question, matrices

$A$ is a $n\times n$ matrix whose elements are all non-negative rational numbers and $Det(A)$ is a non-zero integer.Under what condition the following is true?
(0) There exist a positive integer $M$ such that $M\cdot A^k$ is always a element in $\mathbb{Z}^{n\times n},\ \forall k\in\mathbb{N}.$ 
It's obviously that the following condition is sufficient. 
(1)$A\in\mathbb{Z}^{n\times n}$   
Is (0) equivalent to (1)? If not,can you give a equivalent condition to (0)?

Comment: Is this homework? If so, not on-topic here.

Comment: I don't understand the votes to close (or the downvote).  Is there an easy answer I'm not seeing?

Comment: @Steven, I mostly agree with your comment, but it's not that hard to find an example to show the two conditions are not equivalent.

Comment: Condition (0) is equivalent to the characteristic polynomial of the matrix having integer coefficients (one direction is the Cayley-Hamilton theorem, and the other one can see by showing that $\cup A^k \cdot \Bbb Z^n \subset (\tfrac{1}{M}\Bbb Z)^n$ is finitely generated free and changing basis).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a linear algebra problem that is not that compleicated in the end, *presented without motivation.*

Answer (score 7):

This is an elaboration on Tyler Lawson's comment: For $A \in \mathrm{Mat}_{n \times n}(\mathbb{Q})$, the following are equivalent:

(0) There is a nonzero integer $M$ so that $M \cdot A^r$ has integer entries for all $r \geq 0$.

(1) $A = g B g^{-1}$ for some $B \in \mathrm{Mat}_{n \times n}(\mathbb{Z})$ and $g \in GL_n(\mathbb{Q})$

(2) All the coefficients of the characteristic polynomial $\det(t \mathrm{Id} - A)$ are integers.

Proofs: $(0) \implies (1)$. Let $\Lambda$ be the subgroup of $\mathbb{Q}^n$ generated by $A^r \mathbb{Z}^n$ for all $r \geq 0$. Then $\frac{1}{M} \mathbb{Z}^n \subseteq \Lambda \subseteq \mathbb{Z}^n$ so $\Lambda$ is a free abelian group of rank $n$. Choosing a basis for $\Lambda$ places $A$ in the required form.

$(1) \implies (2)$ Obvious.

$(2) \implies (0)$ Let the characteristic polynomial be $t^n + b_{n-1} t^{n-1} + \cdots b_1 t + b_0$. Then, by the Cayley-Hamilton theorem, 
$$A^{r+n} = - \left( b_{n-1} A^{r+n-1} + \cdots + b_1 A^{r+1} + b_0 A^r \right).$$
So, for $s \geq n$, the matrix $A^s$ is in the integer span of $A^0$, $A^1$, ..., $A^{n-1}$. Choosing $M$ large enough to clear the denominators of these finitely many matrices proves the result.

Note that description (1) makes it easy to find many examples.

Answer (score 3):

They are not equivalent.  Take a (15,8,8) design ( or the 15 by 15 0-1 matrix associated with the order 16 Sylvester-Hadamard matrix ). Multiply all elements by 1/2, and call the result A.  AA is an integer matrix equal to 2I + 2J, and so every larger power of A is also an integer matrix. But A is half (!?!) of an integer matrix with nonnegative entries and determinant of size 2.

Edit: As Gerry mentions, there are examples of smaller order that are not very hard to find.
(It helps to start with an integral matrix with determinant divisible by a power of an integer.)

Comment: $15\times15$?! There's a $2\times2$ that shows they're not equivalent.

Comment: With nonnegative entries?  I considered 2 by 2 orthogonal matrices, and then decided to try a design.  Certainly present a simpler example if you wish; my mind has not yet hit on it.

Comment: Masked Avenger:  Gerry is probably thinking of something like $$\pmatrix{3/2&5/4\cr 1&3/2\cr}$$

Comment: $$\pmatrix{1/2&3/2\cr5/2&7/2\cr}$$